# Unable to load application in Android Studio emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

I can't open the application I'm developing in Android Studio emulator, It is showing the following message in the log

```
Could not open Selected VM debug port (8700). Make sure you do not have another instance of DDMS or of the eclipse plugin running. If it's being used by something else, choose a new port number in the preferences.

Unable to open connection to: localhost/17.253.38.253:5037, due to: java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out
```

Following is the port listening by adb

```
adb 14528 unnikrishnan.b 10u  IPv4 0x7e537943f4599ac9  0t0  TCP localhost:5037 (LISTEN)
```

This happened after I upgraded to android studio 3.1.2. How I can fix this issue?

Thanks,
Unnikrishnan B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can be caused by an ip address in the file etc / host, sometimes you enter an additional to make tests and it is not deleted, you must check that in your file this

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
:: 1 localhost
```

you can also ping the address 127.0.0.1 to check for an answer, `$ ping localhost`

additional information that can helps you

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37126279

Comment: `ping localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.039 ms`

Comment: What is this IP 17.253.38.253 . is it something I configured somewhere. Should I change it?

Comment: try to set the file like this 127.0.0.1 localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
:: 1 localhost however, make a backup with this ip that you have

Comment: Thanks for the help! it's working. I backup my hosts file a created a new one with only `127.0.0.1 localhost` and is woking fine.