# Android Studio / ADB suddenly stopped initializing/connecting/working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, adb, android-virtual-device

As of today (19 December 2018) anything ADB-related in Android Studio just stopped working. This is happening in all installations of Android Studio (Android Studio 3.2, Android Studio 3.4 Canary 8, and so on).

Basically, the "Select Deployment Target" window is always blank. It shows "Initializing ADB" for a few seconds, but then that stops and ... nothing. No plugged-in devices, no running emulators/virtual devices, no already-created emulators.

I have tried:

- Installing a new version of Android Studio
- Installing the latest Canary version of Android Studio 3.4
- Uninstalling and re-installing Android SDK Build Tools, Android Emulator, Android SDK Platform Tools and Android SDK Tools.
- Stopped running Android Studio.
- Rebooted my machine (Mac running Mojave)
- Unplugged and re-plugged my physical device (Pixel 2)
- Changing the Run/Debug Configuration to run on a certain device automatically -- The virtual device starts but the apk is not installed on the device/it never runs.
- Calling adb kill-server and adb start-server from the command line.

(Interestingly, the previously-created emulators DO show up in the Run/Debug Configurations window if I select Deployment Target Options/Target - Emulator and examine the "Prefer Android Virtual Device" dropdown list.)

(Also interestingly, "adb devices" from the command line shows all plugged-in and running virtual devices correctly.)

Is anyone else seeing this and have you been able to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Huh. After trying for hours to fix this, I stumbled somehow on this: [Unable to load application in Android Studio emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50629323/unable-to-load-application-in-android-studio-emulator/50629400)

I haven't changed my hosts file in ages but I opened it and checked it and the one line:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

was commented out:

```
# 127.0.0.1 localhost
```

When I uncommented that line, I started seeing devices in the "Select Deployment Target" window again.

I have **zero** idea how or why my hosts file changed.